# NameError: uninitialized constant Rpush::Gcm I'm trying to use rpush for my mobile app. But I keep getting this error

Tags: android, notifications, rubygems, sinatra, push

So I was trying to use rpush for the push notifications of my mobile app using this gem : https://github.com/rpush/rpush. I'm using the sinatra framework. But I keep getting this error, even though I wrote --> require 'rpush' on the top of my file. Can someone experienced in ruby help me? I'm new to ruby so please bear with me. Here's my code

```
require 'rpush'

Module Notifier

def rpush_client
app = Rpush::Gcm::App.new
app.name = "App-Name"
app.auth_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
app.connections = 1
app.save!
end


def notify(user_id,alert)
  rpush_client
  session = db_find_one('dbname.sessions',{user_id: user_id})
  if session.present?
    device = session['devices'].first
    token = device['device_token']
    n = Rpush::Gcm::Notification.new
    n.app = Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("App-Name")
    n.registration_ids = ["token", token]
    n.data = { message: alert }
    n.save!

    Rpush.push
  end
end

end
```

I know its a dumb question but tired of looking for it on here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bundler with Sinatra? If so, you shouldn't need to explicitly require Rpush. See here: http://bundler.io/sinatra.html

Comment: If I remove the "require 'rpush'", it gives me an error saying Uninitialized constant Rpush. I have a feeling I need to put something like "require 'rpush/gcm'". But I've tried that, It doesn't work

Comment: Hey, years later you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

#### What I did wrong

In my case, I just installed rpush with

```
bundle add rpush
```

and faced the same error.

#### What I should've done

As clearly mentioned in [README.md](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/blob/master/README.md#getting-started), you have to run the following command after add rpush to Gemfile:

```
$ bundle
$ bundle exec rpush init
```

#### What you'll get for correct installation

This will generate `config/initializers/rpush.rb` and (lots of) migration files.

You may want to run migration after that.

### Tips

I recommend to use [rpush-redis](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/wiki/Using-Redis).

You don't need to run extra migrations with it. You can safely get rid of garbage migration files.

`config.redis_options` may resemble the following:

```rb
Rpush.configure do |config|

  # Supported clients are :active_record and :redis
  config.client = :redis

  # Options passed to Redis.new
  config.redis_options = {
    url: ENV.fetch('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0'),
    password: ENV.fetch('REDIS_PASSWORD', '')
  }
end
```